# How To Have Fixed Side Popup

Tags: html, css, popup, tailwind-css

Im trying to figure out how to create a side popup/banner similar to the popup that appears when right clicking and pressing `search` on a mac.

[image]

Im not really sure what to search or how to start, could someone show me what to do and push me in the right direction (preferably using tailwind but i can adapt)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's called `popovers`, you can search any tailwind element or components site you'll find a lot

1. https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/popover/
2. https://tailwinduikit.com/components/webapp/UI_element/popover
3. more in https://www.google.com/search?q=make+popovers+in+tailwind

**note**: the code snippet have problems on cdn tailwind, it works on normal tailwind CLI one

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
);
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new Popover(popoverTriggerEl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex justify-center flex-wrap">
  <button type="button" class="
          px-7
          py-3
          bg-red-600
          text-white
          font-medium
          text-sm
          leading-snug
          uppercase
          rounded
          shadow-md
          hover:bg-red-700 hover:shadow-lg
          focus:bg-red-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0
          active:bg-red-800 active:shadow-lg
          transition
          duration-150
          ease-in-out
        " data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-title="Popover title" data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
    Click to toggle popover
  </button>
</div>
<!-- Required popper.js -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```